# Trying to output Data in Visual Web Developer 2008 from ACCESS Database using VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, datareader

Ok I can successfully connect to my Access database but I am still learning on how to output that data. Here is the run down.

I am designing a page where the user inputs the customer ID and then gets a list of incidents for that customer. Then I would like the user to be able to add a survey about the incident.

Problem I am running into is the ability to display this data. I have tried various method. Eventually I want to be able to display the data into a listbox and have them select it and take the survey but I am not near that far yet. Here is what I have on the connection and my attempt which doesn't work to output the data:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT [Title], [Description] FROM [Incidents] WHERE ([CustomerID] = textbox1.text)"
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "C:\Users\Allen PC7\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\1-A SportsPro\App_Data\TechSupport.mdb"
        Dim myCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim myReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        Try
            While myReader.Read()
                Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString() + ", " + myReader.GetString(1))
            End While
        Finally
            myReader.Close()
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

I just can't get anything displayed in the console and instead get an error saying Dim myReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()...System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing in a proper value to the SQL:

```
"SELECT [Title], [Description] FROM [Incidents] WHERE ([CustomerID] = textbox1.text)"
```

It will try to look for `CustomerID` that is equal to the database value "textbox1.text". Since this is probably the wrong data type and a table/column that doesn't exist, you are getting the error.

You should be using a [parameterized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT [Title], [Description] FROM [Incidents] WHERE ([CustomerID] = ?)"

Dim myCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Integer, 4).Value = textbox1.text
```

This will fail if the value in `textbox1.text` is not of the right type - you should both validate and convert to the right type (my code assumes an integer).

Comment: So how would I just make a simple query to take the value from textbox1 and display the Title and Description for that particular inputed customer ID number? i have had little to no luck finding this information online.

Comment: @allencoded - Answer amended, example added. I suggest reading the MSDN documentation for the OleDB classes.